# How to show a static image with flask in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, image, flask

It's simple enough in the HTML portion of the code:

```
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='#UserData/user/profile/profile_pic.jpg')}} " width='200' height='200' />`
```

Works perfectly fine with no issues.

However, suppose I create a div and want to do something like

```
document.getElementById("image_location").innerHTML +=
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='#UserData/user/profile/profile_pic.jpg')}} " width='200' height='200' />`
```

Then it doesn't work.
It encodes the values to:
[image: static/#UserData/${username_list[i]}/profile/profile_pic.jpg]

and fails to load the image. Is there something fundamental I'm misunderstand about flask?

This is the error:
[image]
Thanks for your time. It should be hard to reproduce, just load up a flask app and try to load an image in javascript.

ps. (The JavaScript portion has to be located in the script portion of your html file, not in a separate js file your referring to)

Comment: Is your file path correct? `#UserData/user/profile/profile_pic.jpg`

Comment: yes it is, there was another way though

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in another way, for those of you who run into this: you can encapsulate the same kind of logic in loops in HTML, which I didn't know you could do

[image]

Comment: No images of code, please. Post code in text format.